# Persist scroll position of TabBarViews in NestedScrollView in flutter during swipes

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a List of Tabs in a Tabbar.

However, I have an issue. If you run the sample code below and scroll to item 30 on Tab 1 then swipe to Tab 2 and back to Tab 1 you will immediately notice that item 30 in Tab 1 is no longer focused. The scroller has jumped to item 1 instead. This is weird.

I have tried everything possible to ensure the scroll position of each ListView is preserved irrespective of how many times I swipe away and back to it.

Here is a full runnable sample code showing exactly the issue I'm facing.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SampleListApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const SampleListApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SampleListApp> createState() => _SampleListAppState();
}

class _SampleListAppState extends State<SampleListApp>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController? _tabController;
  late ScrollController _scrollViewController;
  int _currentTabIndex = 0;

  _handleTabChange() {
    setState(() {
      if (_tabController != null) {
        _currentTabIndex = _tabController!.index;
      }
    });
  }

  _initTabController() {
    _tabController?.dispose();
    _tabController =
        TabController(initialIndex: _currentTabIndex, vsync: this, length: 2);
    _tabController?.addListener(_handleTabChange);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initTabController();
    _scrollViewController = ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 0.0);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        controller: _scrollViewController,
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool boxIsScrolled) => [
          SliverAppBar(
            title: const Text("Hello World"),
            bottom: TabBar(
              indicatorColor: Colors.white,
              isScrollable: true,
              labelColor: Colors.orange,
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
              tabs: const [
                Tab(
                  text: "Tab 1",
                ),
                Tab(
                  text: "Tab 2",
                )
              ],
              controller: _tabController,
            ),
            pinned: true,
            floating: true,
            forceElevated: boxIsScrolled,
          ),
        ],
        body: TabBarView(
          key: UniqueKey(),
          controller: _tabController,
          children: const [
            ChildView(),
            ChildView(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ChildView extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChildView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ChildView> createState() => _ChildViewState();
}

class _ChildViewState extends State<ChildView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<String> itemList =
        List.generate(100, (index) => "Item ${index + 1}");
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 16.0,
              left: 16,
              right: 16,
            ),
            child: TextField(
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
            ),
          ),
          ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: itemList.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(itemList[index]),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What can I do to always preserve the scroll positions of my ListViews when swiped away and back

Comment: Have you tried AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin ?

Comment: @Swayangjit Yes, I tried that it still didn't preserve the scroll positions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the **UniqueKey** from TabBarView, the TabBarView won't rebuild when you setState and add **AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin** mixin like this:

```dart
class ChildView extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChildView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ChildView> createState() => _ChildViewState();
}

class _ChildViewState extends State<ChildView>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    final List<String> itemList =
        List.generate(100, (index) => "Item ${index + 1}");
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 16.0,
              left: 16,
              right: 16,
            ),
            child: TextField(
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
            ),
          ),
          ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: itemList.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(itemList[index]),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```